# Parallel tasks in a GUI

Tags: python, opencv, user-interface, pysimplegui

I'm trying to create a control panel for a machine which has a couple of webcams to monitor the state remotely.

I'm currently using PySimpleGUI for the graphical interface and I divided the main window in two parts:

- left Column: command panel, here I have all the buttons and other stuff that are required to control the machine
- right column: webcam viewer, here I put two Image objects, which are updated from the webcam feed every "refresh_time" (currently 0.5 s)

The problem arises when I try to connect to the webcams. I use the cv2.VideoCapture(url) command, which takes a relevant fraction of a second to answer when called. This delay, repeated twice each time the webcams are refreshed, is put into the while loop that controls the window and everything else, thus effectively freezing everything for almost a second.

Obviously the result is a pretty laggish window, and even worse, the animation I put into one of the commands moves smoothy just between webcam refresh and then jumps to sinchronize with the actual time.

this is the sample code of the webcam displaying:

```
#Main window loop
while True:

    # update current time of the window
    current_time = time.time()-start_time
    
    # get window values for GUI interaction
    event, values = window.read(timeout=15)
    
    #WINDOW CLOSED
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
        capture1.release()
        capture2.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
 #%% --------------------> WEBCAM DISPLAY <----------------------------
    # # WEBCAM CAPTURING

    if current_time-last_time > refresh_time:
        last_time = current_time
        #Try camera connection
        try:
            # get camera frame
            #requests.get(url1, timeout = 0.5) this was even slower
            capture1 = cv2.VideoCapture(url1)
            ret1, frameOrig1 = capture1.read()
            #if the camera can be read, update the frame and display the image
            frame1 = cv2.resize(frameOrig1, frameSize)
            imgbytes1 = cv2.imencode(".png", frame1)[1].tobytes()
            window["cam1"].update(data=imgbytes1)
            capture1.release()
        except:
            #if the camera can't be read display static image
            window["cam1"].update(data=staticGIF_data)    
    
        # # update webcam2
        try:
            # get camera frame
            #requests.get(url2, timeout = 0.5) this was even slower
            capture2 = cv2.VideoCapture(url2)     
            ret2, frameOrig2 = capture2.read()
            #if the camera can be read, update the frame and display the image
            frame2 = cv2.resize(frameOrig2, frameSize)
            imgbytes2 = cv2.imencode(".png", frame2)[1].tobytes()
            window["cam2"].update(data=imgbytes2)
            capture2.release()
        except:
            #if the camera can't be read display static image
            window["cam2"].update(data=staticGIF_data)

        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

My Idea would be to have the video capturing part of the code taken out from the window while loop, and let it run continuously in background, maybe updating a jpg image into a program folder, which is then just read from the main loop.

Is it possible to run a second loop in parallel? I know there are some libraries which allow parallelization of processes, but I will need to export the whole thing in .exe for the end user, and I fear that the parallelization would be pretty hard to implement.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Threading and multiprocessing are ways to run in parallel.  It depends on just how in parallel, whether you need shared data, etc.  Lots of variables in making a decision on the design.

Comment: I think you're after a threading implementation based on running in the background and sharing local resources.  This will remove the need to write to a file for example.  Just tell the main event loop using `write_event_value` when there's something new to show/use.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Process and manger from muliprocssing.

This sample code might help you:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager

def getImage(image,url, staticImage):
    lastCamTime = time.time()
    while True:
        if refresh_time < time.time()-lastCamTime:
            lastCamTime = time.time()
            try:
                # get camera frame
                # requests.get(url1, timeout = 0.5) this was even slower
                capture1 = cv2.VideoCapture(url)
                ret1, frameOrig1 = capture1.read()
                # if the camera can be read, update the frame and display the image
                frame1 = cv2.resize(frameOrig1, frameSize)
                image = cv2.imencode(".png", frame1)[1].tobytes()
                capture1.release()
            except:
                image = staticImage# if the camera can't be read display static image
            lastCamTime = time.time()


#Main window loop
with Manager() as manager:
    cam1Image = manager.Array()
    cam2Image = Manager.Array()
    cam1Process = Process(target=getImage, args(url1,cam1Image,staticGIF_data))
    cam2Process = Process(target=getImage, args(url2, cam2Image, staticGIF_data))
    cam1Process.start()
    cam2Process.start()
    cam1Process.join()
    cam2Process.join()
    while True:
        # update current time of the window
        current_time = time.time() - start_time
        # get window values for GUI interaction
        event, values = window.read(timeout=15)
        # WINDOW CLOSED
        if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
            capture1.release()
            capture2.release()
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break
        # %% --------------------> WEBCAM DISPLAY <----------------------------
        # # WEBCAM CAPTURING

        if current_time - last_time > refresh_time:
            last_time = current_time
            # Try camera connection
            window["cam1"].update(data=cam1Image))
            # # update webcam2
            window["cam2"].update(data=cam2Image))
            #cv2.destroyAllWindows()  ##I don't understand why you did this every loop
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, as soon as I can I'll try and implement that. What if my two processes were the main GUI window and a background camera feed updater which saves an image for the GUI to read? this way the GUI has always something to read, and doesn't have to wait for any answer.

Comment: `getImage()` cannot return image data even though you seem to intend this.